# Prolog - Multiplication of matrix with its transpose

Tags: matrix, prolog, transpose, multiplication

I need to find the product of the matrix A with its transpose A^t, so I should get a third matrix B=A*A^t.
Example: `A=[[1,2],[3,4]]` (then `A^t=[[1,3],[2,4]]`) so `B=[[5,11],[11,25]]`
(each sub list is a row of the matrix)

Firstly I think that this should be easier as the columns of A^t are the rows of A. So for the dot product of the row of A with the column of A^t I think I can use this:

```
sum([M|Ms],[N|Ns],Sum) :-
    sum(Ms,Ns,S),
    Sum is S+M*N.
 sum([],[],0).
```

I also can't use clpfd or if-else.

I've been stuck and don't know what to do next.

Comment: Well you already found out how to calculate a single element. So now you have to write a predicate that calculates your `sum` n^2 times.

Comment: That is, for every two rows in the matrix.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687499/matrix-multiplication-prolog

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you can use the dot-product of the rows of matrix `A` for this. Although you probably better name this function `dot_product/3` instead of `sum/3`.

The only task that is left, is to calculate this dot product for every two rows in `A`. So the *i,j*-th element of *B* is the dot product of *A<sub>i</sub>* and *A<sub>j</sub>*.

We can construct a predicate that calculates a row of *B* with:

```
transprod_row(A, AI, Row) :-
    maplist(dot_product(AI), A, Row).
```

Furthermore we can then calculate the `transprod/3` with another `maplist/3`:

```
transprod(A, B) :-
    maplist(transprod_row(A),A,B).
```

or in full:

```
dot_product([],[],0).
dot_product([M|Ms],[N|Ns],Sum) :-
    dot_product(Ms,Ns,S),
    Sum is S+M*N.

transprod_row(A, AI, Row) :-
    maplist(dot_product(AI), A, Row).

transprod(A, B) :-
    maplist(transprod_row(A),A,B).
```

This then generates:

```
?- transprod([[1,2],[3,4]],B).
B = [[5, 11], [11, 25]].
```

The code is not yet the most elegant, nor is it very efficient, since *B<sub>ij</sub>* is equal to *B<sub>ji</sub>* so we can save half of the work. Furthermore if elements in the matrix are missing, then we can not calculate the product. I leave this as an exercise.